# How to implement a binary search algorithm for a Coldfusion application

Tags: coldfusion, binary-search-tree, cfc

I'm building a new application using Coldfusion as the business logic layer or controller in an MVC pattern and wanting to setup a binary search algorithm to handle username lookup on a registration function. Are there any documented instances of implementing a binary search algorithm in Coldfusion/sql?

**Code Below. Note this is far from perfect.**
**Just a rough attempt at trying to translate the syntax into CFML**

```
<cffunction name="binarySearchFunc" access="public" returntype="boolean">
    <!--- Define array collection  variable and target --->
    <cfargument name="collection" type="array">
    <cfargument name="target">
    <!--- If the target is empty, return false --->
    <cfif not isDefined(#argument.target#) or is Null>
    <cfset returnValue = "false">
    <cfreturn returnValue >
    <!--- Else set the high, mid and low params for binary search --->
    <cfelse>
    <cfparam name="low" type="integer" default="0">
    <cfparam name="high" type="integer" default="#ArrayLen(collection)#-1" >
    <cfparam name="ix" type="integer" default="">

   <cfscript>
    While( low LTE high){ 
    <!--- set the mid variable  equal to the mean  value between the low and 
   high --->
     ix = (#low# + #high#)/2
    <!--- set a variable equal to  compareTo method of the target below --->
     intVar = #target#.compareTo(collection[xi] <!--- equivalent CF syntax 
     ??? --->
     if (intVar LTE 0 ) {
         //target value less than collection[i]
        high = ix - 1;
     }
     else if (intVar GT 0 ){
         low =  ix ++ 1 ; }
    else {
        var returnValue = "true";
        return returnValue;
     }
    }
   </cfscript>
</cfif>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: are you allowed to write one from scratch

Comment: yes that is allowed for the project. I'm mostly trying to get a grasp for how to start writing one in Coldfusion. I've seen  some implementations done in C++ or or C, just not Coldfusion.

Comment: the logic will be the same in any language. are you having a tough time with the coldfusion syntax?

Comment: I know how to set the variables and I get the general flow of the syntax but  I lose clarity on the visualization of it when thinking of how to implement it applies to binary search of a query of  usernames.

Comment: share the code you have come up with so far and ill see if i can help you

Comment: Back up a step. Why have you decided to roll your own look-up function instead of using functionality built into the DB (which is where you SHOULD be running this code, not in CF)?